# Stacked left and right arrows

Tags: symbols, article

Of all the arrows available, I can't seem to find something that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a reason for this? The `\leftrightharpoons` is the closest alternative. But I would rather have the arrows look like in the image above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: See, e.g. `\rightleftarrows` in table 146 of the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @Schweinebacke None of the symbols listed is like that, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Schweinebacke That document was awesome. Mathabx package got the symbol (page 71).

Comment: There are six different versions of `\leftrightarrows`/`\rightleftarrows` listed in the comprehensive list, but none of them are identical to your image (the arrows are positioned a bit different, with the start of one arrow directly above/below the tip of the other).

Answer (score 11):

Here's a code for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lrarrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\lrarrow@\relax}}
\newcommand{\lrarrow@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\mkern6mu\rightarrow$\cr
    \noalign{\vskip1pt}
    $\m@th#1\leftarrow\mkern6mu$\cr
  }}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\lrarrow B_{\lrarrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand{\lrarrow}{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackanchor[\dimexpr-2.5pt-4\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\,\,\rightarrow}%
                                     {\SavedStyle\leftarrow\,\,}}}}}
\begin{document}\Huge
$A\lrarrow B_{\lrarrow}$


$\scriptstyle A\lrarrow B_{\lrarrow}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand{\lrarrow}{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{\renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \stackanchor[3\LMpt]{\SavedStyle\,\,\rightarrow}{\SavedStyle\leftarrow\,\,}}}}}
\begin{document}\Huge
$A\lrarrow B_{\lrarrow}$


$\scriptstyle A\lrarrow B_{\lrarrow}$
\end{document}
```

[image]